# pre requisites for python 3.4.2

Tags: python

i just tried to install python 3 .4.2 in ubuntu from an youtube video but it fails due to pip not found or somethinf like that. so before trying to install python on my freshly installed ubuntu, what other downloads should I have?
please link me those downloads

Comment: yes the exact 3.4.2 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped someone with this a few weeks back but I'd already forgotten what I did, so I googled it again and found this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2083626&p=12351981#post12351981

Comment: I'm pleased that my semi-familiarity with your problem helped to solve it.  Any chance I could persuade you to upvote my solution even though it was just a pointer?